# Copy and paste multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

How would I copy a paragraph and paste it in the same div multiple times in jQuery?

Example:

```
<div id="main-content">
<h1> Lorem </h1>
<p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
</div>
```

jQuery makes it:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <h1> Lorem </h1>
    <p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
<h1> Lorem </h1>
    <p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
<h1> Lorem </h1>
    <p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
<h1> Lorem </h1>
    <p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
<h1> Lorem </h1>
    <p> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var toCopy = $('#main-content').children();
for (var i = 1;i < 5;i++) {
    $('#main-content').append(toCopy.clone());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var contentToCopy = $('#main-content').html()

var i = 0;
for(i; i < 5; i++)
{
  $('#main-content').html().append(contentToCopy)
}
```

*Not tested...*